# Rotation around z-axis in xna using kinect sdk c#

Tags: c#, sdk, xna, kinect

i used kinect sdk, c# language to develop game
first i want to take some measurements
i need help to find code which can find angle of rotation of right shoulder around z-axis?

Comment: The z-axis represents the distance from the Kinect.  Rotation around that axis of 180-degrees would mean I'm standing on my head.  Are you referring to a different axis, perhaps the y-axis?  Can you provide a use case for what you are wanting to do with the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use BoneOrientation class of the SDK and remove the rotations with y and x leaving the rotations of z. you can pick right shoulder to get the orientation and remove other places of the matrix so that it only represent the z rotation. If you do not know how to do this please reply. I assume that you have your hands wet on this.

cheers.